# Getting response headers from Beta Graph Api Call using C# SDK

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

Im using the Beta Graph API to create a Teams channel.

According to the beta [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) this returns a `202` and headers that indicate the Team ID

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Content-Type: application/json
Location: /teams/{teamId}/operations/{operationId}
Content-Location: /teams/{teamId}
Content-Length: 0
```

My code

```
 var team = new Team
    {
        DisplayName = className,
        Description = description,
        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            {"template@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teamsTemplates('educationClass')"},
        },
        Owners = new TeamOwnersCollectionWithReferencesPage() { new User() { Id = ownerId } }
    };
   
       await graphClient.Teams
      .Request()
      .AddAsync(team, cancellationToken);
```

The `AddAsync` returns a response which always seems to be null and there doesn't seem to be a way to access the headers through the SDK. I now have to jump through lengthy hoops to get the ID.

Is there any way to get this?

Comment: Start by using a sniffer and see actual response.  You can only get the information you see in the sniffer.  You may want to also capture results from a browser to see if you get same results.  Usually if data is missing you need to modify your request and add headers to change what is in the response.

Comment: @jdweng as the documentation states there is no response body with this specific request, only a set of headers that indicate the information I need. I am using the graph SDK(not HttpClient directly) and there seems to be no way to access them.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK now has the method

```
AddResponseAsync
```

It returns:

```
Task<GraphResponse<Team>>
```

So I've used the following code to extract the team id

```
        string pattern = @"([a-z0-9]{8}[-][a-z0-9]{4}[-][a-z0-9]{4}[-][a-z0-9]{4}[-][a-z0-9]{12})";
        var str = response.Content.Headers.ContentLocation.OriginalString;
        var match = Regex.Match(str, pattern);
        var newteamId = match.Value;
        return newteamId;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the id value of saved team like the follow.

```
var x = response.Content.Headers.GetValues("Content-Location");
```

you get,  /teams/{teamId} format like this.

Comment: As stated in my question I am using the SDK. Not HTTP Client